# Regular expression to find <% but exclude <%@?

Tags: regex, eclipse

Can someone provide me with a regular expression that will find this string : <% 
but will exclude this string : <%@ 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using .NET, the regular expression you're looking for is:

```
<%(?!@)
```

It will also work in non-.NET applications, but some regular expression implementations don't support (?!)

Comment: This would be the best solution, capturing only the <% and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one

```
<%([^@]|$)
```

It matches the end of the string or [^@], which is a character class containing all characters except @

Comment: That will match more than <% .It will include the character after <%

Comment: That doesn't matter for the question at hand - it properly distinguishes <% and <%@ like the asker wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The exact correct answer varies between different regex syntaxes, but something like this should work:

```
<%[^@]
```

or perhaps this, if your regex syntax allows:

```
<%([^@]|$)
```

The latter will also match an occurrence of <% at the end of the string (or line), whereas the first regex probably won't.

Finally, as other posters suggest, this might work too if your regex language has "zero-width negative look-ahead assertions" (like Perl and C#):

```
<%(?!@)
```

Comment: That will match more than <% .It will include the character after <%

Comment: That is true, although arguably it does not matter.  <% is a constant string, so it's enough to find the starting location for it.  If you only want to know whether <% is present (but not <%@), it doesn't matter either.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated request, either of these will work:

```
<%(?!@|-)

<%(?![@-])
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be this ? 
<%(?!(@|-))